# Android Date format inside ListView

Tags: java, android, date, format

Thanks to [Giulio Piancastelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22904/giulio-piancastelli) I now have a list view with multiple line capabilities.  Now I am having an issue formatting the date on the second line.  All the dates are the same.  In the feed they are different.  I need someone to help me format my dates in the format of Day, Month, Year (Thursday, October 27, 2011).

This is the code that **doesn't work**:

```
 List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (RSSItem item : feed.getAllItems()) {
        Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        datum.put("title", item.getTitle());

        String dateStr = item.getPubDate();
        SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"); 
        Date dateObj = new Date();
        try {
            dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"); 

        String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);

        datum.put("date", newDateStr);
        data.add(datum);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
                                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                              new String[] {"title", "date"},
                                              new int[] {android.R.id.text1,
                                                         android.R.id.text2});

    itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

    itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    itemlist.setSelection(0);
```

[image: Repeating date]

If I remove my previous date code it works fine, but is formatted incorrectly.

This code **does work, but is formatted incorrectly**:

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (RSSItem item : feed.getAllItems()) {
        Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        datum.put("title", item.getTitle());
        datum.put("date", item.getPubDate().toString());
        data.add(datum);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
                                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                              new String[] {"title", "date"},
                                              new int[] {android.R.id.text1,
                                                         android.R.id.text2});

    itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

    itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    itemlist.setSelection(0);
```

[image: incorrect date format]

I need someone to help me format my dates in the format of Day, Month, Year (Thursday, October 27, 2011).  Thank you!

Comment: So basically you want to get rid of the 12:00:00 GMT part?

Comment: I want the date to read Day, Month, Year.  Like this: Thursday, October 27, 2011

Comment: Isn't what you desire what we are seeing in the first screenshot?

Comment: Every date is reading the same in the first screenshot.  In the feed that the class is reading it is not the same for every item, as shown in the second screenshot.

Comment: So you want the format from the first, but all the dates should be different?

Comment: @CKallemeres: I strongly suspect that in the log of the code creating the first screenshot, there's a stack trace for each item. You *must* learn to use the diagnostic tools available to you - basically the parsing is failing because you're using the wrong format. If you'd notice that, you'd have significantly reduced the scope of where we'd need to look.

Comment: Okay i see...This means there is an issue of how you are parsing the data and setting it to variables and setting it to the TextView in the listview.

Comment: I would suggest logging whatever your DATE variable is and see what the results for each is returning as. Put it inside your loop or whatever you are using the feed the listview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to *parse* the string with the same pattern that you're later using to *format* it. You should parse it with the pattern that it's already in, which looks like "Fri, 21 Oct 2011 12:00:00 GMT" apparently.

So I suspect you want something like:

```
// You probably actually want to set the time zone of the
// formatting pattern - but you'll need to think what time zone you
// really want. We don't know enough to say. Ditto the locale...
private static final DateFormat PARSING_PATTERN = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US); 
private static final DateFormat FORMATTING_PATTERN = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"); 

...

for (RSSItem item : feed.getAllItems()) {
    Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
    datum.put("title", item.getTitle());

    String outputDate;
    try {
       Date date = PARSING_PATTERN.parse(item.getPubDate());
       outputDate = FORMATTING_PATTERN.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       outputDate = "Invalid date"; // Or whatever...
    } 
    datum.put("date", outputDate);
    data.add(datum);
}
```

Comment: I hitting the catch statement every time now.  How do I solve this problem?

Comment: @CKallemeres: Hang on - I've just spotted that I had too many commas. Try now - I've changed the parsing pattern slightly.

Comment: @CKallemeres: Okay, I've edited it again - to use the US locale explicitly and fix the day and month order. But you should have been able to work that bit out yourself, to be honest - Stack Overflow is meant to be a helping hand; you need to *understand* the solution so that you can work with it yourself. Do you understand the code I've presented? Do you understand that the PARSING_PATTERN has to match your input data?

Comment: I am beginning to understand how the code works.  I am new to programming and this site is the best one I could find to understand how things work.  The part that confused me is why the PARSING_PATTERN  has to be different from the FORMATTING_PATTERN.

Comment: @CKallemeres: Do you understand now? You're trying to change it *from* one pattern (e.g. "Thu, 27 Oct 11 2011 GMT") *to* another pattern (e.g. "Thursday, October 27, 2011")

Comment: I understand now.  Thank you for being patient with me and helping me understand why this works.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:***

You need to change this line:

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Take a look at the formats available to [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  What you change it to is dependent on the format that is returned from the RSS feed you are consuming.

Well, today is Thursday, October 27, 2011.  I think what is happening is that you are getting a `ParseException`, and since you are not handling it, your `dateObj` remains set to `new Date()`, which is right now.

The pattern you are reading in is likely incorrect.  (It is actually the same as the format you want to output, so it seems pointless the way it is.)  Take a look at the pattern coming in from the RSS feed and re-evaluate the pattern you use to parse into a `Date` object.

Also, you probably want to throw a `RuntimeException` if the parse fails, and not swallow the `ParseException`.

```
    try {
        dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't parse dateStr: " + dateStr);
    }
```